# Too many redirects error when change of base url

Tags: redirect, docker

recently I got to manage a Wordpress blog (so I don't know of things made before) and to start doing some edits on it I did a local docker compose as sandbox. When I copied the contents (Wordpress files + mysql db), the website worked well, instead for the links that didn't redirect to the local version but to the production one. So, to make them work (as I am unable to access to administration), I replaced in `wp_options` table `site_url` and `home` values with the local path (`http://192.168.99.100:33080`). However, since I did it, the website no longer loads and finishes into a too many redirects error. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I tried also, instead of add the changes in db, to write them in the `wp-config.php` file (according to [this](https://www.wpoven.com/blog/quick-and-easy-fix-for-err-too-many-redirect-wordpress-error)) but nothing changes.

I am using Wordpress 4.9.8 in HTTP on port 33080 and the container's dockerfile is:

```
FROM php:5.6.35-apache-jessie

RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN echo 'log_errors = On\nerror_log = /dev/stderr' >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

I am very new to Wordpress environment, so assume that if there is something I had to do and I didn't wrote it there, I didn't do it. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I found what's wrong. Despite what written [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40426996/8160995) it seems that the Wordpress I have installed doesn't like port numbers different from 80. In fact, I tried changing my docker-compose port from 33080 to 80 and it started to work fine. In db for `siteurl` and `home` I wrote only `http://192.168.99.100`. I still don't know what to do to make it works with a custom port.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried defining WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME to point to the correct URL? This "overrides" the DB settings.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#WP_SITEURL

If that doesn't work, the next thing to try is the RELOCATE method

https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Relocate_method

Comment: For the first solution, I wrote before that I did it and continued with the redirects. For the second method, I added the `define('RELOCATE',true);` on the config file, did the login, it set the production website... Then, I forced the value in the database but again, too many redirects.